# Как сделать принятое телеграм ботом сообщение переменной

Tags: telegram-bot

Делаю бота на telebot.
Сообщения не проходят обработку.

```
import telebot

a = ['Владимир Голубей 31311131', 'Василий Петрович']

i = ()

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")

kb1 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
kb1.row('привет', 'пока')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'menu'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Рад вас видеть!", reply_markup=kb1)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):

    i = message.text.lower()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Данные: ', list(filter(lambda x:x.startswith(i),a))) # На все что я пишу боту он отвечает словом "Данные". а почему он не выводит строку из массива?


bot.polling()
```

Comment: Какая ошибка выходит?

Comment: я добавил в вопрос

Comment: А что вы здесь "message.text.lower() = i" хотели сделать?

Comment: Я бы хотел чтобы все что присылал пользователь присваивалось переменной i. Затем данные переменной i искались в массиве a, если в какой то из строк массива были найдены сходства, то выводилась вся строка.

Comment: Что Вы в финале хотите получить?

Answer (score 0):

Перепутали переменную со значением:

```py
i = message.text.lower()
```

UPD. Вы пытаетесь отправить пустое сообщение от имени бота. Добавьте в начало сообщения любой текст, чтобы исправить ошибку.

Comment: все равно выходит ошибку. Я изменил ошибку в вопросе.

Comment: @БесконечноеЦукуёми исправил ответ.

Comment: i = message.text.lower()
 bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Данные: ', list(filter(lambda x:x.startswith(i),a))) В данное случае просто выходит слово 'данные'

Comment: @БесконечноеЦукуёми не знаю, какого результата вы ждали. В данном случае текст из сообщения просто не проходит фильтрацию. А это уже совсем другая история...